# Keras Weighted Binary Cross Entropy Stuck

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement weighted cross entropy from TF in Keras.
Documentation from TF site : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits

This is what I do :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

# Create the custom loss function
def weighted_binary_crossentropy(weights):
    def w_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            y_true,
            y_pred,
            weights,
            name=None
        ), axis=-1)
    return w_binary_crossentropy

# Optimizers, Loss and Compile
adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)
weighted_loss = weighted_binary_crossentropy(weights=1)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=weighted_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Traning started but Loss is not getting updated/stuck. My expectation is if I set the weight to 1, then the result will be the same as standard cross entropy loss.
Did I missed something?

Comment: Please include the code of your model, or at least of the output layer